# Aligning inputs ontop & next to eachover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align 2 inputs on top of eachover next to another 2 inputs on top of each other.  Here is what it keeps giving me:

http://prntscr.com/33k6bq

It seems to have no problems with 2 of them, but with another 2 next to them it just doesn't want to work.

Here is the style for them:

**CSS**:

```
.loginbutton {
   font-family: 'Nunito';
   color: #fff;
   font-size: 16px;
   background-image: url(../images/gradient.png);
   background-position: 0, center;
   display: inline-block;
   background-color: #81bb0f;
   height: 71px;
   width: 100px;
   margin-left: 10px;
   box-shadow:0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.25) inset,0 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,.25) inset;
   border: 1px solid #919191;
   -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
   -moz-border-radius: 4px;
   border-radius: 2px;
   padding: 10px
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<form method="post" id="phase-0-form">
  <input type="text" id="habbo-name" placeHolder="Username" size="35" value="<?php echo $template->form->reg_username; ?>" name="reg_username" class="logintext" maxlength="32"> 
  <input type="text" id="email" size="35" placeHolder="Email" name="reg_email" value="<?php echo $template->form->reg_email; ?>" class="logintext" maxlength="48"><br>
  <input type="password" id="password" placeHolder="Password" size="35" name="reg_password" value="" class="logintext" maxlength="32" style="float: left;">
  <input type="password" id="password2" placeHolder="Confirm Password" size="35" name="reg_rep_password" value="" class="logintext" maxlength="32"> 
  <input type="password" id="seckey" size="35" placeHolder="Security Key" name="reg_seckey" value="1111" hidden="yes" class="text-field" maxlength="4" >
  <button type="submit" name="register" class="loginbutton" style="float: right">Register NOW</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Edited thread with html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Updated JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/GaryHarrower/Q7EE5/1/)

You had a `float: right` in your CSS (in input.logintext) - this is what was messing it up.

I also removed `style="float: left;"` from the password input as this is not required

Update: I've re-ordered the fields and added buttons to the divs

**HTML:**

```
<div id="logincontainer">
    <form method="post" id="phase-0-form">

        <div style="float:left;">
            <a href="index"><div class="regbutton">Go back to Index</div></a>
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;">
            <input type="text" id="habbo-name" placeHolder="Username" size="35" value="<?php echo $template->form->reg_username; ?>" name="reg_username" class="logintext" maxlength="32" /><br />
            <input type="password" id="password" placeHolder="Password" size="35" name="reg_password" value="" class="logintext" maxlength="32" />
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;">
            <input type="text" id="email" size="35" placeHolder="Email" name="reg_email" value="<?php echo $template->form->reg_email; ?>" class="logintext" maxlength="48" /><br />
            <input type="password" id="password2" placeHolder="Confirm Password" size="35" name="reg_rep_password" value="" class="logintext" maxlength="32" />
            <input type="password" id="seckey" size="35" placeHolder="Security Key" name="reg_seckey" value="1111" hidden="yes" class="text-field" maxlength="4" />
        </div>

        <div style="float:left;">
            <button type="submit" name="register" class="loginbutton">Register NOW</button> 
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu);
 @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito);
 body {
    background: url(../images/bg2.png) repeat-x bottom fixed;
    background-color: #3aa4e2;
    font-family:'Lato';
    margin-top: 70px;
}
#container {
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    height: 371px;
    width: 780px;
    border: 1px solid #919191;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px
}
input.logintext {
    width: 180px;
    height: 12px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #919191;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.loginbutton {
    font-family:'Nunito';
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-image: url(../images/gradient.png);
    background-position: 0, center;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #81bb0f;
    height: 71px;
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25) inset, 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .25) inset;
    border: 1px solid #919191;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 10px
}
.regbutton {
    text-align: center;
    font-family:'Nunito';
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-image: url(../images/gradient.png);
    background-position: 0, center;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #e70505;
    height: 37px;
    margin-right: 21px;
    width: 100px;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25) inset, 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .25) inset;
    border: 1px solid #919191;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 16px
}
.fbbutton {
    text-align: center;
    font-family:'Nunito';
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-image: url(../images/gradient.png);
    background-position: 0, center;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #3b5998;
    height: 37px;
    width: 100px;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25) inset, 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .25) inset;
    border: 1px solid #919191;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 16px;
    margin-right: 10px
}
.usersonline {
    text-align: center;
    font-family:'Nunito';
    color: #919191;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-image: url(../images/gradient.png);
    background-position: 0, center;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    height: 37px;
    margin-right: 21px;
    width: 100px;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25) inset, 0 0 0 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .25) inset;
    border: 1px solid #919191;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 16px
}
.loginbutton:hover, .regbutton:hover, .fbbutton:hover, .usersonline:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
#logincontainer {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid #919191;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 70px;
    width: 780px;
}
.image {
    background: url(../images/mainimg2.png);
    height: 371px;
    width: 780px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it didn't work, this is what I get
http://prntscr.com/33mzfg

Comment: It looks like you have other CSS somewhere messing this up. Can you post more CSS from the site, or provide a link to the site for us to look at?

Comment: Here you go:
The HTML: http://pastebin.com/a432A8En
The CSS:  http://pastebin.com/XrUPcwyw
Site preview: http://prntscr.com/33nb6u

Comment: I have updated the answer. You had a float:right in the css (input.logintext) which was breaking it. Let me know if it works now for you!

Comment: Thanks a lot man, you're amazing :)
but when I uncomment the buttons, the last button that submits the data doesn't go into the container? http://prntscr.com/33rmj3

Comment: Updated again! Should be fine this time - I added the buttons into divs and re-ordered the fields so they all display in the correct order. Let me know if it works for you, and feel free to ask any questions about what I've done!

Comment: Thanks man, appreciate it a lot, it's working perfectly now, I guess I need to learn to keep my CSS clean so I can understand it when it goes wrong :) <3

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to fix this. With the lack of information you provided, I can suggest you two things:

- simply add a line break (`<br>`) after the second input
- put the inputs inside a container and make sure the container's width allow two input fields to fit in, but not three

Comment: Then use the other one. I had no idea what your code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell from just css and screenshot, but my guess would be to warp them in div like this:

```
<div>
<input />
<input />
</div>
<div>
<input />
<input />
</div>
```

And arrange them later with css